# ¿Puedo agregar más elementos en los atributos de mis objetos?

Tags: java

Estoy creando dos listas añadiendole datos a mis atributos, pero el objetivo de este programa es comparar ambas listas y que los datos que no estén en cualquiera de las dos, se agreguen a una nueva lista, si en mi lista A tengo 2 datos que no estén en la lista B, que esos se agreguen a mi lista nueva, todo mediante objetos.

Esta es mi clase:

```
public class COSTOS implements Comparable<COSTOS> {
    public int referencia;
    public double monto;
    public String descripcion;
    public String NumeroParte;

    //Constructores
    public COSTOS(int referencia, double monto, String descripcion, String numeroParte) {
        this.referencia = referencia;
        this.monto = monto;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.NumeroParte = numeroParte;
    }

    //getters and setters
    //hashcode & equals
}
```

> Clase main

```
ArrayList<COSTOS> Lista = new ArrayList<COSTOS>();

COSTOS LstA = new COSTOS(1781, 359.13, "BISAG.SUP.PUER.TRA.I", "67550T9AT00ZZ");
COSTOS LstB = new COSTOS(1781, 359.13, "BISAG.SUP.PUER.TRA.I", "67550T9AT00ZZ");

Lista.add(LstA);
Lista.add(LstB);

System.out.println("Lista 1 hashcode = " + obj1.hashCode());
System.out.println("Lista 2 hashcode = " + obj2.hashCode());
System.out.println("¿Son iguales? " + obj1.equals(obj2));
```

¿Cómo podría agregar datos nuevos a mi lista B o A para comparar?

Comment: exactamente que querrías agregar a que objeto? sé un poco más específico

Comment: Puros atributos, como los que mencione ahi en el codigo

Comment: Debes poner un identificar a cada objecto en tus listas, una vez tengas identificado cada objecto debes recorrer tus dos listas y empezar a ver cuales objectos estan en la listaA pero no en la lista B

Comment: pero en tu clase COSTOS solo tienes  4 atributos y todos los estás llenando en el constructor, ya no te quedarían atributos por pasar

Comment: Así es, pero si quiero agregar otro dato a mi lista B(que seria mediante ese objeto), cómo lo haría?

Comment: mmmh, un identificador? cómo sería eso?

Comment: Me parece que debes mejorar el código que tienes hasta el momento ya que las listas que dices querer comparar son realmente instancias de tu clase *Costos.java*, es decir, `LstA` y `LstB`.

Comment: Te refieres a si quisieras editar por ejemplo el atributo `referencia` del objeto `LstB` ?

Comment: un UUID, puedes crear un nuevo a atributo llamado id, y generar un UUID a cada objecto de la siguiente manera  `java.util.UUID.randomUUID()`

Comment: Se podría crear una lista pero sin tener que instancias un objeto? solo que tome en cuenta los atributos? @AngelOropeza

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias por la recomendaciones.